# Move one div after another div (near) and set float property

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have divs on my page. There is div .rightColumnBar and .divAttributes
**HTML**

```
    <div class="mainContent">
<div class="pageContent">

<form id="createLead" class="frmDiv clear" action="/leads/create_lead.html?lead_id=3287" name="createLead" method="post">

<div class="divEditLead sldf_columnsContainer">
<div id="hot_div">
<div id="errorBlock">
<div class="leftColumnBr">
<div class="centerColumnBr">
<div class="rightColumnBr">
</div>

<div class="createLeadButtons">
<input id="saveLeadBtn" class="bigButton redButton" name="save" value="Save" type="submit">
</div>

</form>
</div>
<div class="divAttributes frmDiv">
<div id="specHeightIncreaser"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
  .divAttributes {
      border: 1px solid #d1ddd4;
      min-height: 200px;
      padding-top: 10px;
      width: 280px;
    }
    .rightColumnBr {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 15px;
    width: 377px;
    }
```

How can I move (only for front,  not insert as html  element) rightColumnBr to divAttributes and set for divAttributes float property in left?

Thanks.

Comment: First of all, some of your divs are not closed. Please correct the code and upload the missing CSS you are using.

Comment: I edited my html, please check it

Answer (score 0):

If you are aiming script, than you can do CSS changes and DOM manipulation this way:

```js
$('.divAttributes').css({
 'border-color': 'red'
}).after( $('.rightColumnBr') );
```

```css
.divAttributes {
    border: 1px solid #d1ddd4;
    min-height: 100px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    width: 280px;
}

.rightColumnBr {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 15px;
    width: 377px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pageContent">
    <div class="rightColumnBr">
        RCB
    </div>
    <p>
        Text
    </p>
    <div class="divAttributes frmDiv">
        ATTR
    </div>
</div>
```

Also on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/th84mmz0/).

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you want?

```
<div class="pageContent">
    <form id="createLead" class="frmDiv clear">
        <div class="divEditLead sldf_columnsContainer">
        </div>
        <div class="leftColumnBr">
        </div>
        <div class="centerColumnBr">
        </div>

        <div class="createLeadButtons">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="divAttributes frmDiv">
</div>
<div class="rightColumnBr">
</div>


.divAttributes {
    border: 1px solid #d1ddd4;
    min-height: 200px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    width: 200px;
    float:left;
}
.rightColumnBr {
    border: 1px solid #d1ddd4;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 0px;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}
```

Also please go through jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/mayurdandekar/0soLrqv0/

Comment: No, I don't need to move divs , only css changes